# Is there a way to generate the "Push Message Detailed Report" or "Mobile Push Data Extract Report" for all BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush

As there's the possibility to retrieve all email tracking for children BUs and also to check the "include child accounts" in the SMS detail report, I wonder if there's the same so I can run a single report from the parent BU for push messages within all children BU, I couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5 
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_push_account_summary_report.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I couldnt find a way to include children BU detail push data ( or push detail data extract) from the parent BU in a single report. I know I can create the report in each child BU but wanted to avoid this repetitive work

Answer (score 3):

I would make a workaround that there is automation in each of my BU, it will pull and push the data into one place. This is due to Push data, you pull from a BU that belongs to that BU, so you need to pull and then combine all of them.

In detail:

**Step 1**: Create PN report DE

- Create a PN report DE, let's call it **PN report DE**
- DE location: Shared Data Extension folder
- DE fields: go to this [Push Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_push_message_detailed_report.htm&type=5) article to get the field names you want to populate later. Set an additional field in this DE calls **compositePKey** as the Primary Key. The DE should be included these fields: **PushJobId, DeviceID, ContactKey, DateTimeSend, RequestId** for the **compositePKey** field

Note: you may want to extract the Push Message Detail report first to review the data then you can be aware how to configure the field type and length. E.g. MessageContent field does show AMPscript, if used so I set it with text type with 4000 characters length OR the ID fields can have more than 18 characters length (FYI my ID column values resulted was more than 64 characters length).

**Step 2**: Create scheduled report

- Go to Analytics Builder >> Report >> create a `Push Message Detailed Report`
- Go to the report you have created, configure the schedule option something like this:

[image]

Remember to uncheck "Make it unique" option, we would want it to be overwritten after each time the scheduled report runs.

And then this report will be scheduled to run daily with the specific occurrence times you set. It will store the report name you set (E.g. mine is PN_msg_detailed) as a zip file in FTP.

If you encounter the error that "The start time must be greater than the current time." Review this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380879&type=1)

**Step 3**: Create Stagging PN report DE

- Create a **Stagging PN report DE**
- DE location: Data Extension folder in the current BU
- DE fields: have the same fields like **PN report DE** (step 1) but without the compositePKey field

**Step 4**: Create automation to pull and push Push report data

**4.1**: Create a file transfer activity to unzip the zip file

- File Naming Pattern: PN_msg_detailed.zip
- Source File Location: Report

**4.2**: Create an import activity to import the PN report to the stagging PN DE

- File location: Import (ExactTarget Enhanced FTP)
- File Naming Pattern: **MobilePush Message Detail Report.csv**
- Targeted DE: **Stagging PN report DE** (Step 3), data action: overwrite

**4.3**: Create Query activity to populate stagging data to PN report DE

- SQL query:

```
Select
*,
CONCAT(a.PushJobId, a.DeviceID, a.ContactKey, a.DateTimeSend, a.RequestId) as compositePKey
FROM
[Stagging PN report DE] as a
```

- Targeted DE: **PN report DE** (Step 1), data action: update

Note: you should schedule the automation to run daily after the scheduled report run time in the step 2 so you can make sure that the compressed CSV report is already there for the automation run.

---

Repeat steps 2–4 for each of your BUs, and the result is that the PN report DE is combined with all of your BUs.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: I was thinking something like it, ty Duc fro wrtiting it down. Its a pity that mc doesn have the chance to get all from the parent BU